# Cocoa: How to prevent NSSearchField in a toolbar to get first responder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstoolbar

When having a NSSearchField in a toolbar, it automatically becomes first responder when pressing TAB key in the window.
How can I prevent that? I.e. to get the search field to refuse first responder?

Comment: I have added this question after figuring out how to do it, to help others just in case they deal with the same problem.

Comment: In InterfaceBuilder, click on the toolbar item twice to select the NSSearchField (one click selects NSToolbarItem). In the Attributes inspector, tick the "Refuses First Responder" checkbox and Bob's your uncle.

The trick here is that NSToolbarItem cannot refuse the first responder in general. However, the NSSearchField (whose ancestor is the NSToolbarItem) can refuse.

Comment: What good is a search field that can't become first responder?

Comment: It is good in case you want to reach it only through a keyboard shortcut. I.e. prevent TAB key to get into that field. An example is Finder - you cannot get into Search field by pressing TAB key.

Comment: For that you want to manage the window's key view loop. If the search field can't become first responder, then it won't accept focus **at all**, by any means. The user won't be able to type into it.

Comment: I use OS X Lion and Xcode 4.3.2. The search field in the toolbar is set to refuse first responder. And still I can click into it by mouse to type.

Comment: Hmm, that may be a peculiarity of toolbars. It actually strikes me as buggy. I mean, if you really wanted to prevent a field in a toolbar from accepting focus, how else would you do it if not by setting that field to refuse first responder?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But anyway, I would love if you could answer this question by a piece of code you mention above - the window's key view loop. May I ask you for that?

Comment: Some experimentation suggests I was simply wrong about "Refuses first responder". It seems that text fields always become focused on a mouse click whether in a toolbar or not. Maybe it's because the field editor is what actually is first responder in that case. Anyway, the window key view loop doesn't require code. In IB, make sure the window is not set to auto-recalculate the loop. Then connect its initialFirstResponder outlet and connect each view's nextKeyView outlet to form a loop. If a view is not pointed to by some other view's nextKeyView, then Tab should not cycle to it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not tried this yet - to exclude the Search field from the cycle.

Comment: Well, since your search field is in a toolbar, I'm not sure the key view loop applies. Neither the toolbar nor its items are views and thus can't be pointed to by `nextKeyView`, but somehow they are included when you Tab around a window.

Comment: I see. Will try to play around with what. Maybe the tool bar view can be excluded from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Xcode 4.3.2, open up the XIB file, click the toolbar item twice to select the NSSearchField (one click selects NSToolbarItem).
In the Attributes inspector, tick the "Refuses First Responder" checkbox and Bob's your uncle.

The trick here is that NSToolbarItem cannot refuse the first responder in general. However, the NSSearchField (whose ancestor is the NSToolbarItem) can refuse.